# How to convert the email body to something readable?

Tags: swift, email

Iam working on a simple Apple mailkit extension but cant get something readable out of my mails.

```
    func allowMessageSendForSession(_ session: MEComposeSession, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        let mailMessage = session.mailMessage;
        let subject = mailMessage.subject
        let sender = mailMessage.fromAddress.addressString ?? "undefined";
        let data = String(data: mailMessage.rawData!, encoding: .utf8)
```

In data is the header and the mail body. But its filled with so many 'quoted-printable' strings.

Something like this `Viele Gr=C3=BC=C3=\n=9Fe =F0=9F=A4=9D`. It should be `Viele Grüße` .

I already tried the code in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827598/1407823 but it seems to only work with single words. I cannot get it to work with a whole text.

Is there no built in way to parse text like this?

Comment: In what way are you having trouble with a whole text?

Comment: The moment the code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827598/1407823) hits a string it cannot decode and convert to a byte it returns nil. Inside the mail are some characters like `="A`. Thats why i'am searching for robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to decode the message, you need a RFC822 parser for example [MimeParser](https://github.com/miximka/MimeParser) on GitHub, available as Swift Package.

This is an example how to decode the body as plain text, `messageData` represents the raw data of the message

```
import MimeParser

do {
    let messageString = String(data: messageData, encoding: .utf8)!
    let parser = MimeParser()
    let mime = try parser.parse(messageString)
    
    switch mime.content {
        case .body(let body): print(body.raw)
        case .alternative(let mimes), .mixed(let mimes):
        if let plainTextMime = mimes.first(where: {$0.header.contentType?.subtype == "plain"}),
            let decodedBody = try plainTextMime.decodedContentString() {
            print(decodedBody)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

With `subtype == "html"` you get the HTML text, if available